Cmake doesn't see epoxy lib
I'm trying to build ORM-SLAM3, however I have linking error:
[ 39%] Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libORB_SLAM3.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lepoxy::epoxy: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/build.make:605: ../lib/libORB_SLAM3.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:192: CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM3.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2


I have epoxy lib installed:
$ sudo apt-get install libepoxy-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libepoxy-dev is already the newest version (1.5.10-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 87 not upgraded.

Also I have warnings like this:
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:391 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0028 is not set: Double colon in target name means ALIAS or
  IMPORTED target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0028" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "stereo_inertial_realsense_D435i_old" links to target "epoxy::epoxy"
  but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for
  an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

But CMake can't find epoxy. If I add find_package(epoxy REQUIRED)  then my build is failed with error:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:46 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findepoxy.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "epoxy", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "epoxy" with any of
  the following names:

    epoxyConfig.cmake
    epoxy-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "epoxy" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "epoxy_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "epoxy"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

I can't find epoxy-config.cmake file in my system by myself, but as I showed before epoxy is installed.
So how to fix this?

Solution found. To solve this problem it's need to download file from Pangolin repository and put it in project dir, after that in CMakeList.txt add:
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules/)
find_package(epoxy REQUIRED)
include_directories(
${epoxy_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
${epoxy_LIBRARIES}
)

